# Linux Shell Script to look for a file and rename

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My objective is just to rename a file name with date timestamp, inside a simple shell script. File name ends with ".dfr_resp" which is why I am creating a variable by looking for the file ending with .dfr_resp and then later renaming the file to MyFileName with date extension.

Below is my code.

```
#!/bin/bash
date=`date  +%m%d%Y%H%M%S`
cd /app/Informatica/INFA961/server/infa_shared/SrcFiles
FileName=`ls *.dfr_resp`
mv $FileName MyFileName.date
```

The error I am facing is:

```
: No such file or directoryInformatica/INFA961/server/infa_shared/SrcFiles
ls: *.dfr_resp: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `\r': No such file or directory
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
```

Comment: Two things;
First, are you running a bash script, or a shell script? The two are similar, but not the same, and slight syntax differences can cause headaches. From your first line, it looks like bash.
Second, the line `FileName=ls *.dfr_resp` should be `FileName="$(ls *.dfr_resp)". Otherwise, you're setting `FileName` to the string `ls *.dfr_resp`, not the output of the command.

Comment: this should be posted on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please do not add [urgent begging](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) to your posts.

Comment: The \r error is due to the shell script having been written with an editor on a non-Linux system such as Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first off the directory

`/app/Informatica/INFA961/server/infa_shared/SrcFiles`

does not exist.

Which is why you see:

```
No such file or directoryInformatica/INFA961/server/infa_shared/SrcFiles
```

In spite of the bad formatting, it seems you then want to run

```
FileName=`ls *.dfr_resp`
```

This means that the command "ls *.dfr_resp" is executed and the resulting text output is assigned to variable FileName.

*(The above is better written as `FileName=$(ls *.dfr_resp)` but is not ideal in any case. The problem is if there are files called "Alpha", "Beta" and "My Stuff": `FileName` will become "Alpha Beta My Stuff". Are there files "My" and "Stuff"?)*

Now the error you see is `ls: *.dfr_resp: No such file or directory`

Which means there is nothing matching `*.dfr_resp` in the directory in which we are still sitting.

This means `FileName` will stay the empty string.

Thus `mv $FileName MyFileName.date` will actually be `mv MyFileName.date` which is an incomplete command.

I am not too sure why the message

```
mv: cannot stat `\r': No such file or directory
```

appears but for some reason a carriage return is picked up, leading to confusion.

Anyway, fix the directory name first.

Also add the following as first command in your script:

```
set -o errexit
```

so that your script will exit on first error before something bad happens.

Also consider pasting your scripts to

https://www.shellcheck.net/

to have them checked for errors (this should be a bash built-in really, there is too much history and cruft in that venerable hamster...)

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your response. There's actually a directory /app/Informatica/INFA961/server/infa_shared/SrcFiles. Below is my code from Putty.

[adm_a600337@acnjlappd003p PAYMENT]$ cd app/Informatica/INFA961/server/infa_shared/SrcFiles
[adm_a600337@acnjlappd003p SrcFiles]$ pwd
/app/Informatica/INFA961/server/infa_shared/SrcFiles
[adm_a600337@acnjlappd003p SrcFiles]$

Comment: But the error message you posted doesn't mention /app/Informatica... it just goes straight to Informatica... something is removing the first directory in your path (per the error message)

Answer (score 0):

Agree 90% with David but one thing I dont understand is that the first error message doesn't mention the /app/ in the directory name and the full directory path is directly after the word directory... is it possible you have set a unix alias for /app/ to represent backspace?  Have a look at the .profile and any other startup files of the Informatica user's home directory to check for this.

It may be a small thing (even a typo from when you posted here) but I've found its the little things that usually unlock a particularly tricky issue

Answer (score 0):

I was able to execute my script.

Mark is right, i have written the script in Editor on Windows which i guess was causing part of the errors. After i have rewritten the code in Putty, i was able to run it successfully.

```
set -o errexit
date=`date  +%m%d%Y%H%M%S`
cd /app/Informatica/INFA961/server/infa_shared/SrcFiles/chase_paymentech/
FileName=$(ls *.dfr_resp)
mv $FileName File.$date
```

Thank you all, for your insight.